# How to set the config file for SSIS dll

Tags: dll, ssis, connection-string, app-config

I have a dll that I have created being loaded into an SSIS package. That dll references a config file with a connection string in it. For some reason instead of trying to get the connection string from that file SSIS tries to get the connection string from DtsDebugHost.exe.Config. How do I tell SSIS to get the connection string from the right file.